# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, {}>' error in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

while learning how to handle errors in Angular Typescript threw an error

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, {}>'
>   in this code block in my component

```
createPost(post: HTMLInputElement) {
this.service.newPost(post).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.posts.splice(0, 0, post);
  },
  (error: AppError) => {
    if (error instanceof BadInput) {
      // Set form errors and display them next to input fields
      this.form.setErrors(error.originalError);
    } else {
      alert("An unexpected error occurred.");
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);
}
```

The service code returning the observable used by the component code is

```
newPost(post) {
return (
  this.http.post(this.url, post),
  catchError((error: Response) =>
    error.status === 400
      ? Observable.throw(new BadInput(error))
      : Observable.throw(new AppError(error))
  )
);
}
```

I need help resolving the error and an explanation on why the error is thrown or how best to achieve handling errors.

Comment: `newPost` doesn't look right at all, are you missing a `.pipe`? You're using the comma operator, not actually applying the `catchError` to the observable.

Comment: When I try to apply catchError to the observable with `.catchError` I get a this error `Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.` even though i have `import { Observable } from "rxjs";
`

Comment: Then read https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md, because it looks like you're used to the pre-6 way of doing things, but sticking in a random comma isn't going to help.

Comment: Alright, I will read this up now

Comment: You need to use .pipe() and then put catchError inside of that just like you would nap or filter but without the dot. So the comma would be correct if you had another method in the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pipe operator followed by a map operator followed by catchError operator. You will have to import the map operator and the catchError operator from rxjs/operators.  Please see below:

```
.pipe(
    mergeMap(resp => {
        // add logic
    }),
    catchError(err => {
        // add handling 
    })
);
```